# Storing a returned array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, return-value

```java
import java.io.*;
class test
{

    int[] returnArray()
    {
        int[] arr={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        return arr;
    }

    void display(int[] arr)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i]+"\t");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        test obj=new test();
        int[] arr=new int[1];

        arr=obj.returnArray();
        obj.display(arr);
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am storing the returned array in an array of size 1, whereas the size of the returned array is 10. Still, the returned array is printed in full i.e. it's being stored fully in 'arr' array.

I was expecting it to give some error like array out of bounds or storing only one element as corresponding to the size of the array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. What is the question you are having?

Comment: You throw away the array of size 1. Better to write `int[] arr = obj.returnArray();` which is effectively the same. But doesn't instantiate and then immediately lose reference to a one element array.

Comment: to store INTO an array (element), you must do something like `arr[i] = someValue` or `arr[i] = someMethod(...)`

Comment: *System.out.print(arr[i]+"\t");* That's going to leave the cursor in the wrong place, also with a tab after the last element. You don't want that

Comment: Your `arr` does *not* contain an array, it contains a *reference* to an array. You replaced the content of your variable, a reference to an array of size 1, with new content, a reference to a different array of size 10. You made two separate arrays in memory, but variable `arr` can only refer to one of them at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assigning the returned array to the `arr` variable. The previous array it was referencing (the one created by `new int[1]`) is no longer accessible after the assignment, and is eligible for garbage collection.